# WebStorm using downloaded Bootstrap returns 404

Tags: javascript, html, webstorm

I have downloaded e.g. Bootstrap and want to use it in my project.
Everything is referenced correctly but my browser cannot find the files.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:3000/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

I have no idea why because everything looks totally fine. Weird thing also: If I move the whole Bootstrap stuff into the /www folder, it works until next reload and then I see the same error again.

I am on Mac OS X and I have already set permissions for complete directory to WRITE/READ. What could cause this behavior? A picture of the directory is attached.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0V7q.png

Comment: I also cannot use anything for the /node_modules/ folder as it says also "NetworkError: 404 Not Found" :(

Answer (score 0):

Move the `bootstrap-3.3.6-dist` directory and `node_modules` directory into your `www` directory.

All pubicly-accessible resources have to be in that `www` directory.